# How does Selenium Webdriver's ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable method work?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I'd like to know how exactly this function checks if an element is clickable. Does it keep clicking until it succeeds or it just checks the displayed and enabled attributes of the element.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the documentation for queries like this:

https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#elementToBeClickable-org.openqa.selenium.WebElement-

> checking an element is visible and enabled